# Reshape from long to wide and create columns with binary value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am aware of the `spread` function in the `tidyr` package but this is something I am unable to achieve.
I have a `data.frame` with 2 columns as defined below. I need to transpose the column `Subject` into binary columns with 1 and 0.

Below is the data frame:

```
studentInfo <- data.frame(StudentID = c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
         Subject = c("Maths", "Science", "English", "Maths", "History", "History"))

> studentInfo
  StudentID Subject
1         1   Maths
2         1 Science
3         1 English
4         2   Maths
5         3 History
6         3 History
```

And the output I am expecting is:

```
  StudentID Maths Science English History
1         1     1       1       1       0
2         2     1       0       0       0
3         3     0       0       0       1
```

How can I do this with the `spread()` function or any other function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `reshape2` we can `dcast` from long to wide.

As you only want a binary outcome we can `unique` the data first

```
library(reshape2)

si <- unique(studentInfo)
dcast(si, formula = StudentID ~ Subject, fun.aggregate = length)

#  StudentID English History Maths Science
#1         1       1       0     1       1
#2         2       0       0     1       0
#3         3       0       1     0       0
```

---

Another approach using `tidyr` and `dplyr` is

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

studentInfo %>%
  mutate(yesno = 1) %>%
  distinct %>%
  spread(Subject, yesno, fill = 0)

#  StudentID English History Maths Science
#1         1       1       0     1       1
#2         2       0       0     1       0
#3         3       0       1     0       0
```

Although I'm not a fan (yet) of `tidyr` syntax...

Answer (score 8):

Using *tidyr* :

```r
library(tidyr)
studentInfo <- data.frame(
  StudentID = c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
  Subject = c("Maths", "Science", "English", "Maths", "History", "History"))

pivot_wider(studentInfo,
            names_from = "Subject", 
            values_from = 'Subject', 
            values_fill = 0,
            values_fn = function(x) 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   StudentID Maths Science English History
#>       <dbl> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1         1     1       1       1       0
#> 2         2     1       0       0       0
#> 3         3     0       0       0       1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This solution is great...could you please elaborate a bit on the ~+(as.logical(length(.))))). Specifically could you point me to where would I find more documentation on use of "+"? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks thisisrg, here `+` will transform a logical into an integer, `+TRUE` is 1. Thus the result of the call is always 1 unless the length is zero.

Comment: Thanks.  `pivot_wider` actually complex for creating dummy vars but your code also helped me do this with T/F values. I had to change the `data.frame` to `tibble` and won't work without that, not sure why. 

```r
studentInfo <- tibble(StudentID = c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
                          Subject = c("Maths", "Science", "English", "Maths", "History", "History")) 

pivot_wider(studentInfo,
            names_from = Subject, 
            values_from = Subject,
            values_fill = list(Subject = F),
            values_fn = list(Subject = is.character))
```

Comment: Hi James, on my system your code gives an identical output whether I use data.frame or tibble (latest released versions of R and tidyr).

Answer (score 7):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
+(table(studentInfo)!=0)
#            Subject
#StudentID English History Maths Science
 #       1       1       0     1       1
 #       2       0       0     1       0
 #       3       0       1     0       0
```

Comment: Wow, that's a very elegant way to use. But in case of larger data frames, it is giving message like "Error in table : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"

Comment: @sachinv  You might have crossed the limit of the number of observations.