# How to copy attributes from data frame to another data frame

Tags: r

After [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426826/how-to-set-flag-value-based-on-data-that-use-one-hot-encoding), I have data frame like this:

[image: data_pangan]

And I also have a data like this:

[image: my_data]

Data that I need from "my_data":

[image: Data that I need]

How to copy "data_pangan" attributes to "my_data" if that attributes not exist in "my_data"? And how to set the value to "no"?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. What exactly is the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to find the column names that are not in the 'my_data' and assign those to 'no'

```
my_data[setdiff(names(data_pangan)[-1], names(my_data[-1]))] <- "no"
my_data
#  id_kategori Ekstruksi Permisahan Pendinginan Pemotogan Pengeringan
#1           1        no        yes          no        no          no
```

#### data

```
data_pangan <- structure(list(id_kategori = 1:3, Ekstruksi = c("yes", "no", 
"yes"), Permisahan = c("no", "yes", "no"), Pendinginan = c("yes", 
"yes", "no"), Pemotogan = c("yes", "no", "no"), Pengeringan = c("no", 
"no", "yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

my_data <- structure(list(id_kategori = 1, Ekstruksi = "no", Permisahan = "yes"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```