# Convert standard data to wide format?

Tags: r, transform

I have a data that looks like this:
[Sort of like a standard data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaD30.png)

How do I convert it to this format in RStudio?
[Wide Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiAWP.png)

Sorry for the pictures as I don't know how to create tables here.

For each column, there are many other values. And for each value, I would like to transform it into a column. (eg. status columns can have 'Divorced', 'Widowed' etc.)

Comment: Provide the data in `dput()` format, not in the form of images.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to community.pleas read the ```dcast``` or ```cast``` .hope this will solve your query.

Comment: Shu check the answer below, it will help you. Also I have put a line of code describing how to create tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663580/using-tidyr-spread-function-to-create-columns-with-binary-value

Comment: Yes @yogesh. your answer is right and helpful to me also.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have named the described table as df. Apply following operations to get the desired output.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,Status = c("Single", "Single", "Married","Married"),
                 Gender = c("M", "F", "F","F"),Age_Group =c("2","3","2","2"))


knitr::kable(df)

df$Age_Group=as.character(df$Age_Group)

df1 <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(df)
```

Delete the columns if dummies are made.

```
df1=df1[,-c(2,3,4)]

View(df1)
```

Comment: You could also take advantage of the `remove_selected_columns` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data set @Yogesh created, you can use the following code to reshape the data. I used the `melt` function from the `reshape` package and `spread` function from `tidyr` package.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,Status = c("Single", "Single", "Married","Married"),
             Gender = c("M", "F", "F","F"),Age_Group =c("2","3","2","2"))
df2 <- reshape::melt(df, id = c("ID"))
df2$new_col <- paste0(df2$variable, "-", df2$value)
df2 <- df2[, !(names(df2) %in% c("variable", "value"))]
df3 <- as.data.frame(table(df2$ID, df2$new_col))
df4 <- tidyr::spread(x, Var2, Freq)
colnames(df4)[1] <- "ID"
df4
```

This is the output the above code generated -

```
  ID Age_Group-2 Age_Group-3 Gender-F Gender-M Status-Married Status-Single
1  1           1           0        0        1              0             1
2  2           0           1        1        0              0             1
3  3           1           0        1        0              1             0
4  4           1           0        1        0              1             0
```

Hope this helps!