# How to iterate through string of one column to mutate/modify other columns value?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column (x1) containing string values. I am using these string values to modify the corresponding logical values of other columns in the data frame (the other columns are named after possible sub-string values in column x1's strings - i.e., 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird').

I've already figured out how to use strsplit() to parse each string in column x1. I also know how to mutate/modify the other three columns based on those strsplit() results.

What I'm currently stuck on is how to apply the for loop below to each row in my data frame.

```
x0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x1 <- c("Dog, Cat", "Cat", "Dog, Bird", "Cat, Bird, Dog", "Cat, Bird")
Dog <- c(rep(FALSE, 5))
Cat <- c(rep(FALSE, 5))
Bird <- c(rep(FALSE, 5))

example_df <- data.frame(x0, x1, Dog, Cat, Bird)

for(i in 1:length(strsplit(example_df$x1) )){
  example_df[[strsplit(example_df$x1)[i]]] <- TRUE
}
```

So for the example above, I want my code to change the first row of my data frame to have example_df$Dog and example_df$Cat to both be TRUE, but example_df$Bird would still be FALSE for that row. The second row would only have example_df$Cat as TRUE, etc.

Another note: for the example above, I've only provided three animal string values. But I'm looking for a method that will scale adequately for large number of string values. I know it's possible to use copy and paste with this method:

```
example_df %>%
    mutate(Dog = str_contains(x1, "Dog"))
```

But unfortunately, this method is not going to scale well if I have 10 or 20 possible animal substring values in column x1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001569/12400385) answer to your example. You can use `separate_rows` then `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df %>%
  select(x0, x1) %>%
  separate_rows(x1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = x1, 
              values_from = x1, 
              values_fn = list(x1 = is.character),
              values_fill = list(x1 = FALSE))


#----------
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     x0 Dog   Cat   Bird 
  <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
2     2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
3     3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
4     4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
5     5 FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mtabulate` after `strsplit`

```
library(qdapTools)
m1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(example_df$x1, ",\\s+")) > 0
example_df[names(example_df)[3:5]] <- m1[, names(example_df)[3:5]]
```

-output

```
example_df
#  x0             x1   Dog   Cat  Bird
#1  1       Dog, Cat  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#2  2            Cat FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#3  3      Dog, Bird  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#4  4 Cat, Bird, Dog  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#5  5      Cat, Bird FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(example_df[1:2], "x1", sep = ",", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: When I check example_df after ```example_df[names(example_df)[3:5] <- m1[, names(example_df)[3:5]]``` the changes do not appear in the data frame?

Comment: @rlang_dog_cat there was a typo in my code, i.e. a missing `]`  Can you check now. thanks

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm also curious - are there alternative methods if the column indices of the string value names aren't known in advance? For example if I do not know Dog, Cat, and Bird are columns 3 through 5 in example_df? I know that you can always manually find the column indices, but I was just wondering if there's the case that the columns needed are spread out through the data frame or if there's too many columns to manually check etc.

Comment: @rlang_dog_cat i added another method with `cSplit_e`